# get_file_contents execute the PHP part

Tags: php, file

I am trying something like this:

```
$content = get_file_contents("abc.file");
echo $content;
```

The problem is that abc.file contains some HTML tags along with a php statement:

```
<?php require_once('a_php_file.php') ?>
```

How do I get the server to execute the php parts of abc.file  before it being echo(ed).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`include()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php): you might need to make some php configuration changes to let include work on remote files, but typically that's what you do.

Either that or [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), I think.

Answer (score 1):

Use `include`:

```
include 'abc.file';
```